# Would rather similar requests disunited than united?

Tags: typescript, orm, request, prisma

I want to make get DB products information.

There are three condition.
1.category, for paging, bring 12
2.isBest = true, bring 9
3.isNew = true and category, bring 3 products for 5times

If this case, I may make same request with option or separate requests.
They are in different pages.

Plese help me!

I made a united request. but is it ok?

```js
  const {bring,isBest,isNew,page,category} = query; 
  const condition:ConditionType={};
  if(isBest) condition['isBest'] =isBest;
  if(isNew) condition['isNew'] =isNew;
  const products = await prismaHelper.product.findMany({
      orderBy: {
        order: 'desc',
      },
      take: bring,
      skip: bring * (parseInt((page as string) ?? 1) - 1),
      where: {
        category: {
          link: category[1],
        },
        AND: {
          isDeleted: false,
          isShow: true,
          ...condition
        },
      },
    });
```

May I get

```json
{
  products:[
   {
     id:1,
     name:'something',
     ... 
   },
   ...
   {
     id:9,
     name:'something',
     ... 
   },
}
```

Now I have only one product. but I will add products.

Comment: Please [edit] the question, then (1) add a proper DB tag like `sqlserver` or `mysql` or `oracle`, and (2) add the SQL query that you are using or at least have attempted to create. Also show what your tables look like (as text) and give sample data (as text) + expected results (as text).

Comment: Thank you feed and I add orm. I want to know what is the better way separate 3 request or just 1 request?